# A device which notifies an Android device in proximity

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask my question but since I am not receiving the answer anywhere someone on this Q&A site might have had similar issues as mine and found a good solution.

My Android app needs to be notified if the user of the app is very close to certain places. I can calculate this information from GPS data but for detailed calculations, the GPS data is not enough. For example, the app needs to know if the user has left one room and entered another room.

Is there any solution available for my situation? I believe some sort of device might exist in the market that can notify any nearby Android device listening of its proximity to it.

Comment: You can implement this using `Proximity Alert` in `Location Listner` in android. Go to this [http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2012/10/proximity-alerts.html](http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2012/10/proximity-alerts.html)

Comment: I've tried this approach but in my country the GPS data and the location information provided by the network providers are not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example you give, no. Location, proximity and geo-fencing are all very different things. Location is "where am I now" - proximity includes "how far am I from object X" and geo-fencing is "am I within the bounds of a specified area"

Most location data is obtained either through GPS (geo-positioning) or based on facts like "the device is using the signal of a tower with a known location." So "proximity" data is usually based on the device using services that have known locations, not actual proximity based on distances to those devices such as signal strength.

Carriers have data regarding proximity to some extent, for keeping the device connected to the network, but I don't believe they share it. Even if they did, you need to integrate with carrier back-end systems and that's not "an app." Carriers can run traces to get locations, but they don't it regularly.

You could map known tower locations and get signal strength data, but then you need to triangulate to other known signal sources. In others words, knowing how far you are from a bluetooth device does not tell you which direction, so you would need at least 2 signal strength sources (and their relative locations and signal strength map) to determine location. GPS relies on signal strength to several satellites to triangulate device location.

There are not any "radar" devices that I am aware of, nor should you expect them soon. Usually "proximity to a known location" is good enough even for geo-fencing purposes (the device is "within a city" or "near a store"). This is very coarse geo-fencing and essentially doesn't help with the "device left one room and entered another" problem.

But that isn't to say that you couldn't create some kind of signal data for a specialized app in a controlled environment. For example, you may be able to setup devices so that you know the signal strength will be "very strong" for room specific signal sources when the device moves from one room to another. Or setting up bluetooth devices that measure their own signal strength compared to the device you are monitoring and then normalizing that data in some way to determine device proximity and triangulating device location.

A complicated problem that sounds simple... maybe one day it will be.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no API for that, however, if you could for example make your own "Finger print" of the location you might get it rather reliable. For example could for example scan wifi networks available in the excat spot with their signal strenght, and make your own logic for determining when the "fingerprint" is close enough to actual spot to raise the proximity alert.

You of course should first the have the GPS proximity to alert you when you are close enough to start the fingerprinting..